# Displaying a popup overlaying the current activity

Tags: android, user-interface

I am currently working an android app and I am trying to implement a popup menu that overlays current activity, kind of like the new version of Astro.

Below is a screenshot that shows what I am talking about
[image: Astro Screenshot popup menu]

So the menu is what I have circled in the screentshot, so I want this to popup when a user clicks on something e.g. a long press.

I guess it might be an activity that gets loaded but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What Astro uses seems to be the split Action Bar approach. Look at the screenshot on this page... http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html under the section "Layout Considerations for Split Action Bars". In the case of Astro, the bottom bar is normally hidden but a long-press on a folder causes it to appear. Further to that, the "More" action view you show in your screenshot is a collapsed action view but the Astro devs make it automatically expand (appear). In short, if you want to do something similar, just use a split Action Bar.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is indeed create another activity, with a transparent background in its theme. If you are working with Fragments, you can also create a fragment, and I believe you can then position it where you want. However, if you have not been using fragments in your app, I would go for the Activity idea, as it's easier.